Maximum output power at 915 MHz without HAM license
I bought a telemetry module that is able to transmit with a power of 500mW at 915MHz.
I am in the U.S. and - as far as I understood - the 915 MHz does not require a license. However, I am not sure what is the maximum power I can use to transmit, without the need of a HAM license. I tried to contact the FCC, but I did not get any answer yet. I tried to go over the FCC regulation but I gave up :)

Is this an ISM application?

I am planning to use this telemetry module to transmit RTK position from my base stationt to the rover. It is for hobby. So, I believe the answer to your question is yes?

Accordinf to the following site: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/unlicensed-915-mhz-band-fits-many-applications-and-allows-higher-transmit-power, the maximum allowable radiation at 915 MHz is given as a field strength: 50 mv/m at a distance of 3 meters from the antenna. According to the site, this amounts to a maximum radiated isotropic power of -1.23 dBm which is 0.75 milliwatts. Note that higher power levels are allowed if spread spectrum techniques are used.

so, yes, if the telemetry module is doing spread spectrum, its EIRP might be higher! Note that one has to be careful, because EIRP is always higher than output power, since no real-world antenna is a perfectly isotropic radiator. It's easy to figure out whether that device is such a spread-spectrum transmitter, simply by looking up its FCCid.

Thank you all for your answers. The FCCID is 2AP22-HT03-V3. The module is available here: https://holybro.com/products/sik-telemetry-radio-v3.
I tried to look up the product on the FCC database (link: https://www.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid), but I get the error: "There are no applications on file that match the search criteria specified:
Grantee Code: 2AP22 Product Code: HT03-V3"

Just found this: https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/2AP22-HT03-V3
But I guess this is way above my level of understanding. Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

The radio modules use frequency hopping. Allowed EIRP is 1W at less than 50 hopping frequencies. You can set the modules to full output power (500mW) if you assume the monopole antennas coming with the radios have less than 3dBi gain.
